# (distutil + shutil) * copytree =?

Tags: python

I'd like the ignore pattern that shutil's copytree function provides. And I want the src tree to replace all existent files/folders in the dest directory like distutil.dir_util.copy_tree.

I'm a fairly new Python user, and can't seem to find any posts on this.

Comment: Interesting. And what is your question?

Comment: What's the meaning of life? Hehe jk.

Comment: I'd like you use a copy tree function that both, replaces existent files/directories AND can take an ignore pattern. shutils and distutils each have half of the functionality I want.

Comment: And what about using shutil.copytree, but removing the destination directory?

Comment: That would be great if there weren't files in the dest directory I wanted to persist.

Comment: If you'd like to refine your question, please edit your post instead of providing those details in comment form.

Comment: It seems, that unix philosophy of having one tool that makes one thing really good does not apply to copying directories with python. One can overwrite, the other one can ignore patterns. None can both. I WANT RSYNC for python!!!

Answer (score 3):

I was going to say this earler but I didn't. http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html has a version of the copytree function. I looked at it to see if it would just replace existing files and from what I could tell it would overwrite existing files, but it fails if any of the directories already exist. Due to `os.mkdirs` failing if the directories already exist.

The needed imports:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
```

taking `_mkdir` from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82465-a-friendly-mkdir/ (a commenter over there mentions that `os.mkdirs` has most of the same behavior but doesn't notice that `_mkdir` doesn't fail if any of the directories to be made already exist)

```
def _mkdir(newdir):
    """works the way a good mkdir should :)
        - already exists, silently complete
        - regular file in the way, raise an exception
        - parent directory(ies) does not exist, make them as well
    """
    if os.path.isdir(newdir):
        pass
    elif os.path.isfile(newdir):
        raise OSError("a file with the same name as the desired " \
                      "dir, '%s', already exists." % newdir)
    else:
        head, tail = os.path.split(newdir)
        if head and not os.path.isdir(head):
            _mkdir(head)
        #print "_mkdir %s" % repr(newdir)
        if tail:
            os.mkdir(newdir)
```

Although it doesn't take a `mode` argument like `os.mkdirs`, `copytree` doesn't use that so it isn't needed.

And then change `copytree` to call `_mkdir` instead of `os.mkdirs`:

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False):
    """Recursively copy a directory tree using copy2().

    The destination directory must not already exist.
    If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.

    If the optional symlinks flag is true, symbolic links in the
    source tree result in symbolic links in the destination tree; if
    it is false, the contents of the files pointed to by symbolic
    links are copied.

    XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.

    """
    names = os.listdir(src)
    # os.makedirs(dst)
    _mkdir(dst) # XXX
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks)
            else:
                shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
            # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
        except (IOError, os.error), why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except Error, err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except WindowsError:
        # can't copy file access times on Windows
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extending Dan's answer by incorporating the ignore argument and adding shutil to the 'Error' class (for copytree):

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    """Recursively copy a directory tree using copy2().

    The destination directory must not already exist.
    If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.

    If the optional symlinks flag is true, symbolic links in the
    source tree result in symbolic links in the destination tree; if
    it is false, the contents of the files pointed to by symbolic
    links are copied.

    XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.

    """
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    _mkdir(dst) # XXX
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
            # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
        except (IOError, os.error), why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except shutil.Error, err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except WindowsError:
        # can't copy file access times on Windows
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a wokaround with both distutils and shutil:

```
ignorePatterns=('.git')
shutil.copytree(src, "__TMP__", ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns(ignorePatterns))
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree("__TMP__", dest)
distutils.dir_util.remove_tree("__TMP__")
```

Note: This is not an efficient method, because it copies same files twice.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.8 and above, [shutil.copytree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) now has the dirs_exist_ok parameter (defaults to False). To copy the tree without any errors (when the dirs are already existing, set it to True.

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("path/to/src", "path/to/dst", dirs_exist_ok=True)
```